# Convert the date (start and stop) to a time interval so I can compare using Python

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas, time-series

Hello I am working with a .csv file that contains the Birth Date and Death Date of all the presidents. The problem that I am trying to solve is what year is the year that the most presidents were alive. I assume that to do this, I have to convert the dates of the birth and deaths of the presidents to a time series and the presidents who are currently alive, will have to have their death dates changed to present time. Does anyone know I can go about doing this using Python and the packages - Pandas and NumPy? Here is the code I have so far:

Also the date is in this format: Feb 22 1732
If the president hasn't died then his death date is blank

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
#simple problem: find the year that the most presidents
#were alive
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import the presidents.csv and save as a dataframe 
presidents = pd.read_csv('presidents.csv')
#view the first ten lines of the dataframe 
presidents.head(10)
#change the column names to remove whitespace 
presidents.columns = ['President','Birth Date','Birth Place','Death Date','Location of Death']

#save the column names of the dataframe into a list 
columns_of_pres = list(presidents.columns)
#create a data frame that contains just the name, birth and death date of the president
birth_and_deathbirth_and_death = presidents[['President','Birth Date','Death Date']]
```

Comment: You could use the datetime module to calculate date differences.

Comment: Can you add sample of data and desired output?

Comment: You know you're expected to accept the answer that worked for you? http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to solve is what year is the year that the most presidents were alive, then you should just
1) get the year out of your date field `year = 'Feb 22 1732'.split(' ')[-1]`
2) for each president make a list of years in which he was alive. `aliveYears = range(birthYear,deathYear)`
3) use `collections.Counter()` to count which year you find most presidents.

Something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
yearCount = Counter()
for p in presidents:
    birthYear = ....split(' ')[-1]
    deathYear = ....split(' ')[-1]
    for year in range(birthYear,deathYear):
        yearCount.update({year})
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have transformed your dataframe in the following format:

```
president  birth_year death_year
President1       1875       1925
President2       1900       1950
President3       1925       1975
```

(If you need help with that transformation let me know.)

Then the following function will count the number of presidents alive at a given year:

```
def president_count(year):
    return(((df['birth_year'] <= year) & (df['death_year'] >= year)).sum())
```

Indeed, `((df['birth_year'] <= year) & (df['death_year'] >= year))` returns a boolean series, with `true` or `false` depending on whether the president is alive. You then sum the series to get the number of presidents alive.

You can then use a simple loop to get the maximum.